# Magento 2, template changes only show when static folder is removed

Tags: magento2, template

I'm new to Magento 2, but it's really inconvenient and time taking that every time I edit something in my template file, I need to do the following to make the changes displays on the web browser.

1. I need to delete everything from *pub/static*
2. I need to run `php bin/magento cache:clear`
3. I need to run `php bin/magento cache:flush`
4. I need to run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

If I miss any of the steps above, the changes will not show on the web browser, this is really crazy. Is this how Magento 2 works or did I miss something?

I'm using **Magento 2.1.9**

I have set **application mode** to **developer**

Comment: What template/file, specifically?

Comment: It's Magento_checkout/web/template/

Comment: remove existing template file and run this command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: @MoinMalek From which folder I should remove the existing template? from pub/static?